# Can you search on Stack Overflow using regular expressions?

Tags: support, search

Is it possible to search for posts by using a regular expression?

For example:

Search: `“What is [a-zA-Z]+?”`

Comment: I don't think regex is supported, you can use [wildcard searches](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) though. Something like `"What is *?"` would be equivalent to your example

Comment: [How do I search?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) does not show regex support

Comment: In what context? E.g., you can download the [Stack Overflow dump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-dump/info) and use [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) expressions or [Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl)/[grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) to search directly in the XML content (yes, it *can* work very well for one-off purposes).

Answer (score 12):

No.

The closest you get in [on-site search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) is wildcard searching. [SEDE](//data.stackexchange.com) does allow for some more fancy searches, but it's only updated weekly, and you may run into timeout problems for certain searches if you don't properly delimit your search. While it [does not support regex](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224834/332043), it has [some expanded wildcards](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266082/332043) that does let you use `[A-Za-z]`. Doesn't look like there's a way to add quantifiers to the group though, at least when the answer was posted in 2015.

But if you still absolutely need full regex for some reason, you can download the [data dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) and write your own tool for it. Or just write a tool to store it in a database that does have regex capabilities.

Comment: Can confirm that T-SQL's pattern matching abilities have not changed since that post was made. Presumably [so] was running SQL Server 2012-2014 back then and it's currently running 2019, which doesn't add *more* pattern matching feature. For what it's worth too, 2022 doesn't add anything either (at least not in RC1). *If* [so] does have a regex feature on SEDE, it would have to be CLR, and there's no documentation on that.